# What is the meaning of "When I fold, you see the best in me?"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

In Ed Sheeran's *Joker and the Queen* song, it says "When I fold, you see the best in me". What exactly does this mean?

> How was I to know?
> It's a crazy thing
> I showed you my hand
> And you still let me win
> And who was I to say
> That this was meant to be?
> The road that was broken
> Brought us together
> And I know you could fall for a thousand kings
> And hearts that would give you a diamond ring
> **When I fold**, you see the best in me
> The joker and the queen

Comment: ***If all but one player folds on any round, the remaining player collects the pot*** *without being required to reveal their hand. If more than one player remains in contention after the final betting round, a showdown takes place where the hands are revealed, and the player with the winning hand takes the pot*. (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song appears to be using the card game of poker (a game largely based on bluffing) as a metaphor for the singer's feelings for the lady.
"I showed you my hand" in the game would be exposing your cards to the other player(s) but here it means he is not concealing his true feelings.
There are several other references to the game terminology and playing cards in general.
"To fold" in the game means to give up and abandon the hand (round of play) because you believe the other player has a better hand and will win, so

> When I fold, you see the best in me

means "When I stop playing, you see the best in me". In other words

> When I cease trying to conceal the truth (my feelings for you), you see the real me.

Comment: You could add that the "joker" and the "queen" are also court or picture cards in a deck.  Mr Sheeran is a "joker" = a fool, a clown, a jester while the "queen" is his love interest, belongs to a higher class. She sees through his act.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, there are several allusions to poker in the quoted verses. "Show my hand", "fold", "joker and queen". Probably also "a thousand kings" and "diamond" though they're less clear.

Comment: Thank you everyone, now i understood.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed, but I did mention that in my answer. I just didn't want to make it too long explaining all the allusions. I just picked one other as a further example.

Comment: @Jay Yes there is also "hearts" which together with "diamond" are, of course 2 of the 4 suits in a standard pack of cards used for poker.